# Why does `cargo build` not show all errors in my code?

Tags: rust

This code doesn't compile:

```
extern crate iron;
#[marco_use] //misspelled here
extern crate mime;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;

fn main() {
    let mut response = Response::new();
    response.set_mut(mime!(Text/Html; Charset=Utf8));
}
```

it shows:

```
error: cannot find macro `mime!` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:22
   |
10 |     response.set_mut(mime!(Text/Html; Charset=Utf8));
   |                      ^^^^
```

If I add `extern crate hyper; use hyper::mime::*;`, then it shows:

```
error: The attribute `marco_use` is currently unknown to the compiler and 
may have meaning added to it in the future (see issue #29642)
 --> src\main.rs:2:1
  |
2 | #[marco_use] extern crate mime;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I could've seen this earlier, it would've helped me to fix the mistake...

I guess Cargo only shows one error? I could not find anything about this behaviour online. How can I see all errors?

Comment: Adding `extern crate hyper; use hyper::mime::*;` to your code does not produce the second error you state when using Rust 1.23.0. What version of Rust are you using?

Comment: @Shepmaster I am using rustc 1.23.0 and cargo 0.24.0 (on Windows)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compilation process is divided into several stages and if during one of them an error breaks the build, the following stages are not processed further. This is not specific to Cargo, but `rustc` as well (example: [When are numeric literals assigned to default types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595782/when-are-numeric-literals-assigned-to-default-types)).

I haven't seen it officially documented, but the high-level process [has been described by japaric](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/the-big-picture-of-compilation-in-rust/6380/3):

[image]

Comment: So shouldn't the misspelling be found while parsing before macros are expanded?

Comment: @yassin why? It's not a parsing error. Both `mime!` and `#[marco_use]` are typos as far as the compiler is concerned, not syntax errors. It just happens that macros-by-example are expanded before attributes since they can expand *into* attributes. Since the macro cannot be expanded, the compiler stops.

Comment: How did you write this? Where did you get all this information from?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I didn't - it was written by japaric and the description is linked in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I could not read your message fully. This picture is so amazing that I read only first sentence. :D